# Image Slide Show with a timer without using any plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a silde show without using any plugin. 
 I need a timer which reducing its height and changes with the image and timer having a clicking event also. https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/repository/store/sapstore/US/default.html. 
This is the one which I am trying.

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" width="250px" />
</div>

<div id="timer">
<a href="">
<span class="reduce_height">1</span> 
</a>

<a href="">
<span class="reduce_height">2</span> 
</a>

<a href="">
<span class="reduce_height">3</span> 
</a>

<a href="">
<span class="reduce_height">4</span> 
</a>

</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {

    var imgs = ['http://www.academy-florists.com/images/shop/thumbnails%5CValentines_Day_flowers.jpg', 'http://www.everythingbuttheprincess.com/assets/images/babies-in-bloom-fuchsia-flower_thumbnail.jpg', 'http://www.behok.ru/i/a/cat/gerbera.jpg', 'http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg', 'http://gameinfestedent.com/gallery_photo/medium_image/image1322820610_MainPurpleOrchids3_1a.jpg'];

    var maximages = imgs.length; //No of Images
    $(function() {
        setInterval(Slider, 3000);
    });
    var prevIndex = 0;

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            var shuffleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximages);
            if (prevIndex == shuffleIndex) {
                while (prevIndex != shuffleIndex) {
                    shuffleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximages);
                }
            }
            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

            $(this).attr('src', imgs[shuffleIndex]).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: So what's not working? SO is a need help site not a need code site. It might help to look at how other Slide Show plugins do this and since most of them are open source looking at code should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    var imgs = ['http://www.academy-florists.com/images/shop/thumbnails%5CValentines_Day_flowers.jpg', 'http://www.everythingbuttheprincess.com/assets/images/babies-in-bloom-fuchsia-flower_thumbnail.jpg', 'http://www.behok.ru/i/a/cat/gerbera.jpg', 'http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg', 'http://gameinfestedent.com/gallery_photo/medium_image/image1322820610_MainPurpleOrchids3_1a.jpg'];

   var maximages = imgs.length; //No of Images
   Slider();
   setInterval(Slider, 3000);
   var prevIndex = 0, prevPrevIndex = 0;

   function Slider() {
       $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
           do {
               shuffleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximages);
           } while(prevIndex == shuffleIndex || prevPrevIndex == shuffleIndex)

           prevPrevIndex = prevIndex;
           prevIndex = shuffleIndex;

           $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

           $(this).attr('src', imgs[shuffleIndex]).fadeIn("slow");
       });
   }

});
```

I put the `prevPrevIndex` so that images were repeated less often )) you can remove it